# Check strings using enums

Tags: ios, swift, enums

i'm trying to check whether the type string is equal to the num strings, however i cant seem to figure out how i check type against the rawValues of enums. so far i've done this:

However i keep getting `Enum case News not found in type String`

```
enum ContentType: String {

    case News = "News"
    case Card = "CardStack"

    func SaveContent(type: String) {

        switch type {
            case .News:
                print("news")
            case .Card:
                print("card")

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're trying to compare `String` with `ContentType`. The passed argument is `String` but the case is `ContentType`

Comment: Yea i know that, but i just dont know how to check whether the type is equal to RawValue of enum values.

Comment: Since the expression is evaluated at compile time anyway and you have to consider the `nil` case, you can also use literal strings rather than the enum values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by using `enum`'s raw value in the switch:

```
enum ContentType: String {

    case News = "News"
    case Card = "CardStack"

    func SaveContent(type: String) {
        switch type {
        case ContentType.News.rawValue:
            print("news")
        case ContentType.Card.rawValue:
            print("card")
        default:
            break
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write a switch from your String class which is not correct. You should update the SaveContent method with:

```
if let type = ContentType(rawValue: type) {
    switch type {
    case .News:
        print("news")
    case .Card:
        print("card")

    }
}
```